# How can I join these tables to get this count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables :

```
users
id int primary key

questions
id int primary key
user_id int references users(id)

answers
id int primary key
question_id references questions(id)
user_id references users(id)

likes
id int primary key
answer_id references answers(id)
question_id references questions(id)
check answer_id xor question_id
```

A like can either reference an answer or a question, but not both so one foreign key will be null.

user_id in the likes tables is the user who placed the like.

How can I count the number of likes that were placed on each user's questions and answers?

Comment: Are you looking for combined likes of questions and answers, or a column for each total?

Comment: combined .......

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand, you need count likes for each user id, which are earned by answers and questions together.

If so, then one way is:

```
select  coalesce(questions.user_id, answers.user_id) as liked_user_id, count(*) 
from likes
left join questions
on likes.question_id = questions.id
left join answers
on likes.answer_id = answers.id
group by liked_user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select 'questions' as which, count(*)
from questions q join
     likes l
     on l.question_id = q.id
where q.user_id = $user_id
union all
select 'answers' as which, count(*)
from answers a join
     likes l
     on l.answer_id = a.id
where a.user_id = $user_id;
```

EDIT:

If you want the result for *all* users in one row, then a correlated subqueries are a pretty easy method:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*)
         from questions q join
              likes l
              on l.question_id = q.id
         where q.user_id = u.id
       ) as question_likes,
       (select count(*)
         from answers a join
              likes l
              on l.answer_id = a.id
         where a.user_id = u.id
       ) as answer_likes
from users u;
```

Comment: beauty, but you're passing user_id as a param, what I want is one row for each user row that hold that total likes count, so I need to join users as well.

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat . . . That is what the edited version does.